# Create a 3d surface plot with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to create a 3d surface plot with plotly below with the topic label in the hoverinfo text but I get empty plot.

```
df<-structure(list(topicLabel = c("Unassigned Papers", "BERT Model Compression and Optimization", 
                                  "Code Semantics and Language Models", "Multilingual Translation Technologies", 
                                  "Language-Driven Agent Collaboration"), x = c(10.943317, 11.376795, 
                                                                                11.11172, 9.993373, 10.066545), y = c(5.915477, 7.448679, 6.8502655, 
                                                                                                                      5.844873, 8.3468275), z = c(8.941429, 9.370003, 4.6556673, 9.7087345, 
                                                                                                                                                  5.602739)), row.names = c(472L, 782L, 937L, 833L, 638L), class = "data.frame")
library(plotly)
# volcano is a numeric matrix that ships with R
fig <- plot_ly(df,x=df$x,y=df$y,z = as.matrix(df$z))
fig <- fig %>% add_surface()

fig
```